# project.json created when changing target to .net standard (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I want to switch target for Portable Class Library project from classic profiles to .Net Standard. The problem is that it creates `project.json` file which is deprecated. If I install any nuget packages, it also leads to updating this file rather than `.csproj`. I use Visual Studio 2015 and latest version of .NET Core tools for Visual Studio 2015 (Preview2.0.3). Does it mean that I have to switch to VS 2017 or is there a proper way to deal with updated `.csproj` format and .Net Standard using VS 2015?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use csproj, you need to use VS 2017.

Even though csproj for VS 2015 is usable, it involves a lot of hacks and isn't really documented or officially supported (and afaik break in VS 2017 without a migration path), so I strongly suggest to stick with `project.json` or migrate to VS 2017.